# The set of lines through a fixed point in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, grassmannian

I am struggling to solve this question. I have to find the set of lines through a fixed point in $\mathbb{P}^3$ using $Gr(2,4)$. How can I show that this set is inside $Gr(2,4)$ and a subset in $\mathbb{P}^5$ defined by three independent linear equations using Plücker coordinates?

Since I have only learned about basic algebraic geometry, I have tried to solve this by finding a corresponding variety lying on $\mathbb{A}^3$. However, I have no idea how to go further from here. Also, I'd like to approach this question only using Plücker coordinates.

Comment: A point in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is a line in $\mathbb{A}^4$, and a line in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is a 2-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb{A}^4$.

Comment: @user90189 How can I develop an idea from here? I am trying to find three independent linear equations in $\mathbb{P}^5$,

Comment: Suppose that the fixed point is $p=[0,0,0,1]$; any point $q = [q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4]\neq p$ defines a unique line $l(p,q)$ passing through $p$ and $q$. Define the equivalence $q\sim r$ if $q$ and $r$ define the same line passing through $p$. Map $l(p,q)$ to the 2-plane in $\mathbb{A}^4$ spanned by the vectors $p$ and $q$—think of them now as vectors. Show that the map is well defined.